# Select list with input fields

Tags: entities

I would like to have the following field widgets:

[image]

I would like to give the user the possibility to give in 4 nicknames and select the default one that will be shown to other users.

Is there a module for this or something I can work with?

I've searched google but with no success ... .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Double field](https://www.drupal.org/project/double_field) module.

> Double field is a small module written to provide extensions to Drupal's core Fields. By this module you can split your fields up into two separate parts.

I used it for one of my project and works well.